# Merge [supervisord] tag and description into [supervisor]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Supervisor is "a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems". The daemon that runs the service is invoked with `supervisord`. Users that control the service use `supervisorctl`.

I'm not sure about the conventions on SF for tags of daemon programs, but it seems to me that the name of the software is "Supervisor", and the `supervisord` tag is therefore redundant. This is further evidenced by the fact that a number of Supervisor-related questions are tagged with both tags. Could me merge `supervisord` into `supervisor` (or set it as an alternate)?

(The program website uses Supervisor throughout, even though the URL is http://supervisord.org )

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 3):

There are 49 questions tagged [supervisor](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/supervisor) and 74 questions tagged [supervisord](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/supervisord)

In the effort to make as little work for ourselves as possible, can I suggest that the retagging happens in the opposite direction, ergo supervisor into supervisord?

Comment: so there isn't a magical merge command? I'm shocked ;) thanks tom!

Comment: Not that I've found so far... It's a pretty manual process of editing questions.

Comment: Um, yeah, there is a magical merge command...